# Unhandled Exception: Invalid argument: Instance of 'Model' class

Tags: firebase, flutter, exception, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to update my firestore DB with a new model. Model is termed as 'Model' and following is the code that is written to update the same.

**UpdateLogic.dart**

```
var listOfObj = List<dynamic>();
    Model model = new Model('ABC', 1, 18);
    listOfObj.add(model);
    Firestore.instance.collection('xyz').document(id.uid).setData({"newData": FieldValue.arrayUnion(listOfObj)});
```

and my Model class looks like this -

**Model.dart**

```
class Model{

  String name;
  int num;
  int rank;

  Model(name, num, rank){
    this.name = name;
    this.num = num;
    this.rank = rank;
  }
}
```

I'm not sure where I'm doing a mistake as I'm getting exception while running this:

> Unhandled Exception: Invalid argument: Instance of 'Model'

Comment: Why the constructor is written as `EquipmentModel` ?

Comment: oh that's just a spelling mistake I actually renamed it but forgot to paste it here. @MidhunMP

Comment: I made an edit @MidhunMP. Thanks for seeing that. Can you help me with the actual issue?

Comment: In which line you are getting that exception ?

Comment: In the last line while using .setData method

Comment: maybe its caused because of the 'num' keyword try changing that, num is an abstract class in dart: core, comment if it worked for you

Comment: @Henok It's not working, I changed it.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to add a list of custom class instances as a field of a document field, if you create a custom class **you must make set its object as a document** but for other types Fieldvalue works fine ( meaning you can add it as an array ).

For more info about supported types [read this](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/data-types)

Comment: Alright! I will try to make changes according to the suggestions and let you know then. Thanks.